How many Triangles in the Picture?
In Puzzling Stack Exchange was this question,   courtesy of Zamir Bezgoev
How many Triangles in the Picture?
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/128909/how-many-triangles-in-the-picture/128925?noredirect=1#comment358862_128925

An answer was found, for the picture of side $n=8$, the answer is $648$
For the square grid a formula for the total was found, like this e.g. for $n=16$
$2\times 16^2 + 4( 8(T_8 +T_7) - 2(T_6+T_4+T_2...T_0) + T_{15} + 2(T_{13} +T_{11} +T_{9}...T_1)) =4784 $
$T$ is for triangle number
If $n=16$, the numbers in the above are from
$8=\frac{n}{2},   $
$7=\frac{n}{2}-1,   $
$6=\frac{n}{2}-2,   $
$15 = n-1,   $
$13=n-3$
Then using formulae for the sum of squares it could be proved that if $\frac{n}{2}$ is even the the total is $\frac{1}{12}(13n^3+15n^2+20n)$
The formula is the same but with $-1$ at the end if $\frac{n}{2}$ odd
Florian F found a similar formula for odd numbers
$\frac{1}{12}(13n^3+15n^2-n-3)$
(see the link to the puzzling stack exchange)
Is there a formula for rectangular grids, of lengths $a$ and $b$?
Since the $a$ and $b$ will appear symmetrically in the formula, as rotations of the rectangle seem to give the same result, then it's suspected that there is a formula of this form for rectangles
$\frac{1}{12}(13ab \sqrt{ab}+15ab +xa+xb+y)$
where $x$ and $y$ are constants
.

Is the figure supposed to be a $4\times 4$ grid or $8\times 8$ grid?

There are 2 solutions there with a slightly different approach. Were you able to extend what they did?

@Pranay an 8x8 grid, question edited to make clearer

good to see question asked here too :)

Note that all triangles are right isosceles, and the hypotenuse is either horizontal (or vertical) with an even length, or it is diagonal with any length. And the hypotenuse can give 2 (or 1 sometimes) triangles. You can try to find how many hypotenuses you can make, and then try to see how many of them give only 1 triangle.

I will focus on the case where both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $4$. Also assume $a\geq b$.
A formula is derived by iterating over all segments of what the hypotenuse of the triangle can be and then simplifying the sums.
There are two kind of points in the grid. Those that have diagonal lines going through them and those that don't. If we place the grid in a coordinate plane so that its corners are $(0,0), (a,0), (a,b), (0,b)$ then this is decided by the parity of the sum of the coordinates. Call a point even/odd by this parity. See this doodle at Desmos (the calculations are also there, but it got a bit messy).
Let's group the triangles by type.
Type 1 triangles, hypotenuse is horizontal

By symmetry, the number of type 1 triangles is twice of those that are pointing up. An up pointing triangle is given by two even points on a vertical line such that half their distance is at most the distance of the line to the top. By taking the lines separately according to the parity of the $y$-coordinate we have the formula
$$
T_1 := \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{b}{2}-1}\sum_{x=0}^{\frac{a}{2}-1} \min(\frac{a}{2}-x, b-2i)
+
\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{b}{2}-1}\sum_{x=0}^{\frac{a}{2}-2} \min(\frac{a}{2}-1-x, b-1-2i) \\
= \frac{b}{2}\left(2-\frac{a}{2}\right) + 2\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{b}{2}-1}\sum_{x=0}^{\frac{a}{2}-2} \min(\frac{a}{2}-x, b-2i)
$$
Notice that we've only used that $a$ and $b$ are even and this formula works for all evens. But the divisibility (of $a$) by $4$ comes necessary when we start to simplify this formula, since there's the cut-off point $i=\frac{b}{2}-\frac{a}{4}$. This comes as follows. To decide the minimum, consider the inequality
$$
\frac{a}{2}-x < b-2i
$$
i.e.
$$
x > \frac{a}{2}-b+2i.
$$
Then we need to consider is this in the boundaries for $x$, i.e. between $0$ and $\frac{a}{2}$. The upper one is always true, but $0$ gives the cut-off. Then simplifying the sum by writing it in parts is trivial, although quite messy (that's why I'm only doing the "divisible by $4$" case).
We have
$$
T_1 =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{a^3}{48} + \frac{a^2b}{8} + \frac{a^2}{16} + \frac{a}{12} &\text{ if }2b\geq a \\
-\frac{ab^2}{4}-\frac{b^3}{6}-\frac{b^2}{4}+\frac{ab}{4}+\frac{b}{6} &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
Type 2 triangles, hypotenuse vertical
This is similar to first one by rotation and now since $a \geq b \geq \frac{b}{2}$, we won't have a cut-off in the first sum. But by the cut-off value in the second sum, we also need to assume $b$ is divisible by $4$. The count is given by the first case of type 1 with $a$ and $b$ switched i.e.
$$
T_2 := -\frac{b^{3}}{48}+\frac{ab^{2}}{8}+\frac{b^{2}}{16}+\frac{b}{12}.
$$
Type 3, hypotenuse diagonal

By symmetry, count of these is $4$ times by the count of North-East pointing ones. Let's call that $T_3$. Now, given any two distinct points on a diagonal line (with slope $-1$), the NE-triangle is inside the rectangle. So
$$
T_3 = \left(\frac{a-b}{2}+1\right)\frac{b\left(b+1\right)}{2} + \frac{1}{12}b\left(b-2\right)\left(2b+1\right)
$$
Here we only used that $a$ and $b$ are even. There are $\frac{a-b}{2}+1$ "full lines" having $b+1$ points; and the "left over" lines is twice $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{b}{2}-1} \binom{2k+1}{2}$.
Combined total number of triangles
So we have $2(T_1+T_2) + 4T_3 = $
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{24}(-a^3 + 6 a^2 b + 3 a^2 + 30 a b^2 + 24 a b + 4 a - 9 b^3 + 3 b^2 + 36 b)
&\text{ if } 2b \geq a \\
\frac{1}{24} b (42 a b + 36 a - 17 b^2 - 9 b + 44)
&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}.
$$

Note: the symmetries come by flipping the rectangle accordingly. The pointingness changes and it fits if and only if the flipped also fits.

Thankyou for the answer.  It's really good, but I'll need a bit of time to look over it carefully!
